# AMPPS Problem with MySQL database after upgrade to version 3.9 manually

Tags: mysql, ampps

I just upgraded AMPPS to 3.9 manually and the problem is that it doesn't start when I keep my old MySQL database, when i move them to another folder AMPPS starts normally, I did backup of databases wrong way, I mean I just copied folders with all these files, I didn't do backup through phpmyadmin, is any way to get back these databases to work? I tried with innodb_force_recovery = 1 but it didnt worked, I placed it directly below the mysqld header. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome! This question needs more detail. How is your database server configured? What are the actual errors you see when it fails?

Comment: windows, linux or mac? (Windows and mac is available 3.9. Linux is only available 3.8)